# Need Help Fetching Current Location/POI/Beacon Using "@situm/react-native" Library

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-cli

I'm currently working with the "@situm/react-native" library, and I'm encountering difficulties retrieving the current location, Point of Interest (POI), or beacon information. I've attempted to obtain the current location using the following code snippet:

Sample code

```js
SitumPlugin.setUserAndPassword("....<email>", "...<password>");
SitumPlugin.requestAuthorization()
  .then(() => Situm.startPositioning())
  .then(() => fetchCurrentLocation())
  .then((location) => {
    const userLocation = location.coordinate;
    console.log("location: ", location);

    // Use the userLocation to fetch nearby POIs or perform actions // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error fetching user position: ", error);
  });
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been successful, and I'm reaching out for guidance on how to properly retrieve the current location, POI, or beacon information using the Situm library. Any insights or corrections to my code would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I am currently working on implementing wayfinding in my React Native application using the "@situm/react-native" library. I have already outlined my attempted solutions in the problem details section, and I'm specifically seeking help using the Situm library without introducing any additional libraries.

The goal is to display a route from the current location (POI) to a selected POI. I've referred to the example provided in the Situm GitHub repository at https://github.com/situmtech/react-native/blob/master/example/src/examples/wayfinding/NavigateToPoi.tsx. However, it seems to demonstrate navigation between two selected POIs rather than from the current location to a selected POI.

Any insights, corrections, or guidance on achieving wayfinding from the current location (POI) to a selected POI using the Situm library would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

my coding environment is like -->

```
System: 
  OS: macOS 14.1.2 
  CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1 
  Memory: 67.44 MB / 8.00 GB 
  Shell: 
    version: "5.9" 
    path: /bin/zsh 
Binaries: 
  Node: 
    version: 21.3.0 
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/node 
  Yarn: 
    version: 1.22.21 
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn 
  npm: 
    version: 10.2.4 
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/npm 
  Watchman: 
    version: 2023.12.04.00 
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman 
Managers: 
  CocoaPods: 
    version: 1.14.3 
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/pod 
SDKs: 
  iOS SDK: 
    Platforms: 
      - DriverKit 23.0 
      - iOS 17.0 
      - macOS 14.0 
      - tvOS 17.0 
      - watchOS 10.0 
  Android SDK: 
    API Levels: 
      - "31" 
      - "33" 
      - "34" 
    Build Tools: 
      - 30.0.2 
      - 30.0.3 
      - 31.0.0 
      - 33.0.0 
      - 33.0.1 
      - 34.0.0 
    System Images: 
      - android-31 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a 
      - android-32 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a 
      - android-33 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a 
      - android-34 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a 
    Android NDK: Not Found 
IDEs: 
  Android Studio: Not Found 
  Xcode: 
    version: 15.0.1/15A507 
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild 
Languages: 
  Java: 
    version: 18.0.2.1 
    path: /usr/bin/javac 
  Ruby: 
    version: 2.6.10 
    path: /usr/bin/ruby 
npmPackages: 
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found 
  react: 
    installed: 17.0.2 
    wanted: 17.0.2 
  react-native: 
    installed: 0.68.1 
    wanted: ^0.68.1 
  react-native-macos: Not Found 
npmGlobalPackages: 
  "*react-native*": Not Found 
Android: 
  hermesEnabled: false 
  newArchEnabled: false 
iOS: 
  hermesEnabled: false 
  newArchEnabled: false
```